# List with a parameter which extends more than one type

Tags: java, generics

With generic methods it's possible to extend more than one type, e.g.:

```
<T extends MyClass & MyInterface> void foo(T bar)
```

Is there a way to specify a List with a parameter which extends more than one type?

```
List<MyClass & MyInterface> myList;
```

doesn't work...

This would allow the following:

```
class A extends MyClass implements MyInterface{}

class B extends MyClass implements MyInterface{}

myList.add(new A());
myList.add(new B());

MyClass c = myList.get(index);
MyInterface i = myList.get(index);

foo(myList.get(index));
```

Comment: What semantic do you expect? derived MyClass OR MyInterface, derived MyClass AND MyInterface, other

Comment: All entries should extend both (-> and)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is NO.

Depending on your semantic expectation you will find a workaround

One possible workaround for foo

```
   <T extends MyClass> void foo(T bar) {
     if (bar instanceof MyInterface) return;
   }
```

Probably the best approach is to create a type supplying both type.
The drawback is, all interesting classes needs to derived from that class

```
abstract class MyClassInterface extends MyClass implements MyInterface {}

List<MyClassInterface> myList;


<T extends MyClassInterface> void foo(T bar)
```

The naive approach just to supply both methods will cause ambiguities, so it is not a possible (for "AND", for "XOR" it would be valid)

```
<T extends MyClass> void foo(T bar)

<T extends MyInterface> void foo(T bar)
```

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer, just wanted to confirm. Is there a reason they don't allow this, given it is already implemented for methods?

Comment: Note:
<T extends SomeClass> void foo(T bar)
==
void foo(SomeClass bar)

Comment: I think it would be possible to do so, but it would be hard to express a special syntax and there are probably too less cases where it would be useful

Comment: The use case was when the class hirarchy couldn't be changed. I guess I would to have to maintain to separate lists in that case. Funny enough, I just realized that an unrelated refactoring makes it possible now to have a common parent. This solves my current use case. Still pity this is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely impossible, unless the types belong in the same type hierarchy (in which case you would specify `T extends TopMostBase`).

If it were possible, this would essentially break the entire idea of generics (you can as well specify `List<?> myList` and handle it as if there were no generics at all, doing all your typechecking manually.)

Comment: `this would essentially break the entire idea of generics` can you please elaborate on this statement please? from what I understand, that the OP wants his generic type `T` to *extend* `MyClass`, AND *implement* `MyInterface`. Why would that break the idea of generics? :\

Comment: @amit: gee, I do NOT understand that, based on the provided syntax. From `List<MyClass & MyInterface>` I'm inferring that he wants to store instances of `MyClass` OR `MyInterface`. Seems logical?

Comment: See my updated sample in the question. As stated above, I'm expecting "and" behaviour not "or".

Comment: His edit clears he does want `T` to both extend `MyClass` AND implement `MyInterface`. Was this statement referring only to the OR assumption and is now invalid?

Comment: @Puce: `MyClass implements MyInterface`, so you don't need the `& MyInterface` part in your tentative syntax.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov I don't have control over MyClass (third party). And MyClass is not the direct parent class but one further down the hirarchy chain.